# Error when building application using TFS 2013

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, windows-store-apps, tfsbuild

When I try to build my Windows Store application using TFS 2013, I get the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets (2480): File 'C:\Builds\1\{AppName}\Manual Build\bin\{AppName}\BundleArtifacts\neutral.txt' not found
```

I also get the following warning:

```
The specified solution configuration "Release|AnyCPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since my configuration is set to Release|x86, not Release|AnyCPU. I also do not know what is causing the neutral.txt error. I've been searching for answers and cannot seem to find what might be causing this.

If anyone has anything that might lead to a solution, I welcome anything. I have been trying different configurations, different settings, different build settings, etc to try and get this working, and nothing seems to help.

**Edit:**

I have resolved the second warning, and do not know what is causing the first error

Comment: There are project release settings and there are solution release settings. I'm guessing your project release is set to x86 but your solution is set to AnyCPU. Right click the solution node and select Configuration Manager and change it there.

Comment: My solution is set to x86, every project is set to x86, and my build is set to use x86. I'm not sure where else to change

Comment: Are you using custom build commands?

Comment: I am not. Should I be for this?

Comment: No, it just looks like there is based on your first error using variables in the path.

Comment: That's what is confusing me so much. I can't figure out why this should be happening. I'm not sure why neutral.txt isn't being created, or *why* it is needed

Comment: @RonBeyer, I have resolved the AnyCPU issue. I am still getting this issue with the neutral.txt. Any ideas?